# Paste register contents from :reg screen

Tags: register, paste

`:reg` displays the contents of the numbered and special registers. Is there a way to then paste a register but retain the output of `:reg` on the screen? This avoids the need to store the register name in my short term memory.

Typing `:pu <register>` is close, however `put` will paste the register `linewise` rather than `characterwise`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! What do you mean "without leaving this screen" and why is that important? Why not just go back to Normal mode and use `"xp` (assuming register "x")? And yes `:put` is always linewise. Do you want something that will be *always* characterwise, or that will be linewise or characterwise depending on whether the register contains newlines (as the `p` Normal mode command does)? Please [edit] your question to add more context on these two parts of it.

Comment: Thanks @filbranden for the suggestions. For your question on characterwise v linewise, I'd like the behaviour to be whatever the behaviour is for when `"rp` is executed in normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:normal[!]` to run normal-mode commands after pressing `:`, which should keep the output from `:registers`/`:display` present.

For example: `:normal! "rp` pastes from the `r` register. Elide the `!` if you have a special mapping for `p` that should be used.